# jQuery Ajax cross browser/cross OS

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-browser, operating-system

Is there any reason why a jQuery Ajax request to the server would work on Firefox for Mac and not on Firefox for PC?

Comment: Posting the code/JavaScript in question would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, install FireBug and take a look at the contents of the request in each browser.

http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: I already have, the response of the ajax request shows nothing is returned at all from the query. So...wtf? is there any significant difference in the two browsers?

Comment: @Sam have you verified that both browser are sending exactly the same request? Are they sending the same variables and values? And yes, code would be nice. Maybe just your .ajax() function?